# Jest assert for an element not to be in the document after `n` seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am testing my component's error state after fetching a request.
When the request fails, I update the component state to show the error message, and after 3000ms I update the state in a useEffect to hide the error.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/dom";
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('Throws an error for wrong credentials', async () => {
const {
  getByText,
  getByRole,
  getByLabelText,
} = render(<Login />);

expect(getByText(/Admin login/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

const emailField = getByLabelText('Admin email');
const passwordField = getByLabelText('Password');
const button = getByText('Sign in');

userEvent.type(emailField, 'wrongemail@gmail.com');
userEvent.type(passwordField, 'Wrong666!!!');
userEvent.click(button);

expect(getByRole('progressbar')).toBeInTheDocument();

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(window, 'setTimeout');

await waitFor(() => expect(getByRole('alert')).toHaveTextContent('These credentials do not match our records.'));
await waitFor(() => expect(getByRole('alert')).not.toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

Jest throws an error for the error element to be in the document for the assertion `await waitFor(() => expect(getByRole('alert')).not.toBeInTheDocument());`

> expected document not to contain element, found `<div class="sc-bczRLJ iXcWnZ text " color="gray-primary" role="alert" title="">These credentials do not match our records.</div>`  instead

Here is my Login component.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { Text } from 'core/components/text';

import { login } from 'reducers/auth';

export const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch<SharedDispFn>();

  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');

  const onSignIn = async () => {
    const loginResponse = await dispatch(login(loginData));

    if (!loginResponse.status) {
      setLoginError(loginResponse.message);
    } else {
      navigate('/dashboard');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoginError('');
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [loginError]);

  return (
    <Form checkFormValidation={setFormIsValid} onSubmit={onSignIn}>
      {loginError && (
        <Text color="gray-primary" role="alert" children={loginError} />
      )}
    // Rest of the code ...
    </Form>
  );
};
```

In Jest documentation they say [How to mock setTimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks), but the fact is it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spying on setTimeout doesn’t wait for the function to execute. `jest.runAllTimers();` is what you’ll utilize to fast forward any timers in your code. Check out the “Run All Timers” section in the link you sent to see the documentation on how to use it.

Also, once you get the async code to work, using `getByRole` will throw an error trying to get an element that doesn’t exist. Instead use `queryByRole`, which won’t fail if an element is not found. That documentation can be found here: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/

Comment: That helped !!! Before your answer, I also was trying to solve it and `jest.advanceTimersByTime(moreThanSetTimeoutSeconds);` also solved the issue.
I can't see any real-world usage difference between these 2 options.
Also, my tests are too slow I don't know why. I guess wrapping them in waitFor also makes them slow but not that much. For example, they are taking 300ms-900ms.Any thoughts about it ?

Comment: That can be challenging to solve for, but looking at your code, my initial thought would be to remove those two waitFor functions. Those are both async functions that take time to execute. By fast-forwarding the jest timers, you either will not need the waitFors anymore or will only need one.